# Why is WPF loosing terrain with Silverlight 4 coming?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, desktop-application

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does WPF still have to offer over Silverlight 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4)
>   [Why change from WPF to Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758337/why-change-from-wpf-to-silverlight-4)

I'm working on a WPF application. We considered using Silverlight instead of WPF, but decided we want a full blown desktop application with the whole unique desktop application feeling and advantages that gives. However, starting today there has been a lot of buzz out there about Silverlight 4 being announced at PDC09, and people stating that there aren't many arguments left to choose WPF over Silverlight (4).

So; what's the buzz about Silverlight 4? Why can Silverlight now be used instead of WPF? And when should WPF still be used?

Comment: This is a near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4

Comment: How about that.. Sorry - didn't find it when searching. Will close.

Comment: I think you mean "buzz" instead of "fuzz".

Comment: Voted to close due to the partial duplicate mentioned above, and rephrased in a new opposite question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758337/why-change-from-wpf-to-silverlight-4

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Indeed ;-) Changed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fuzz is that Silverlight 4 will have many of the most commonly used features of WPF that were previously lacking.

The reason Silverlight 4 can be used instead of WPF is it now has the ability to run outside a browser and access the local filesytem.

WPF should still be used when you need features that aren't available in Silverlight 4.  See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4) for a discussion of which features those are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only speculating as to why, but I'd imagine that the recent hype behind Silverlight 4 is simply because it's the latest thing to be announced. WPF has had its fair share of updates in .NET 4.0, so I don't think it's going anywhere.

One of the biggest differences between Silverlight and WPF is that Silverlight is [sandboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29), so I still see a place for WPF in desktop applications.

Comment: Sandboxing is a big pro for using Silverlight. But it's also a big con. :)

Comment: The sandboxing would be a problem for me, but I thought I heard there is better machine access in SL4? But still restricted I guess?