# What is the future of WPF and silverlight ? Why are there two different ui toolkits?

Tags: wpf

Will WPF die out and be replaced by a silverlight that continues to be improved ? What is the direction of bothh ...i am asking as i have heard of MS possibly dumping WPF primarily because of percieved or actual performance impact on the snappyness etc of the UI.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-our-strategy-with-silverlight-has-shifted/7834

Comment: no, he wants an educated reply from someone who knows more about this subject.

Comment: @Adrien - LOL, Loved your comment!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758300/why-is-wpf-loosing-terrain-with-silverlight-4-coming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4

Comment: Whats wrong with introducing q that are a bit more challenging to answer other only allowing basic boring questions that can be answered by a trivial scanning of some documentation ?

Answer (score 3):

WPF is for desktop applications, Silverlight for webbased (ala flash) ones, and also for the new Windows Phone 7, Silverlight is just a subset of wpf adjusted for different platforms.. Also - it really depends on the coding, as with everything. If you execute everything in the UI Thread, of course the UI won't be as responsive. I'm coding a wpf application and it is as snappy as a win forms one.

Comment: You are ignoring "trusted silverlight" apps for the desktop. Follow the "desktop" link from MSDN: WInForms, WPF, _SilverLight_ and C++

Comment: So where are the WPF apps from MS - no office, outlook, notepad etc only visual studio ?

Comment: A rewrite of a software requires certain causes to justify spending manhours on it. If these causes are not met (ie. no real advantage doing the rewrite, doing a rewrite simply because you can, no resonable ROI on the endavour) a rewrite is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively unlikely that WPF will die out or be replaced by Silverlight any time soon. Silverlight can't create the kind of rich client applications that WPF can, and like it or not, desktop applications aren't going away any time soon.

Not to mention, Microsoft has written the interface for several of its major software packages in WPF (Visual Studio and Expression Studio). Many of the things these applications are required to do simply can't be done in the kind of sandboxed environment that Silverlight can provide.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had been wondering and should have realised

Comment: Theres nothing elsee after VS and ES thats WPF... What about office ?