# Silverlight 4 and XBAP

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am just curoius to know whether silverlight 4 is going to replace XBAP completly!. Like Full trust XBAP, Can we do everything with current Silverlight 4?. Any comments?.

Comment: This appears to be similar, if not a duplicate, to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4

Answer (score 3):

Technically its not a replacement.  XBAP delivers the full richeness of WPF and the .NET Framework still missing from Silverlight even when elevate Privs are enabled.

However, IMO, Silverlight 4 would appear to deliver enough to give those who might have considered XBAP pause for thought.  To the degree where I would expect that whilst XBAP would continue to be supported it would get sidelined.

Answer (score 2):

XBAP is in-browser only isn't it? Silverlight 4's trusted mode is only out of browser, so if you want to do anything trusted in browser you still need to use XBAP.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the trusted mode requiring out of browser, I believe it can only access user specific portions of the hard drive, like the users desktop, my documents, etc.

Tim Heuer has a few videos already up on the Silverlight.Net site

http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/local-file-access/

Answer (score 0):

They'll probably restrict the use of unsafe code and PInvoke in Silverlight 4 to a greater degree than in XBAP.

Comment: If I remember reading correctly, you can't do PInvoke in anything Silverlight; full trust out of the browser or not.  This would still require XBAP or similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking they will still restrict file-system access in silverlight.  Otherwise, how do you know that silverlight app your running isn't depositing something nasty (trojan, virus, etc.) on your hdd?  I am sure there are other areas things that silverlight still just won't be allowed to do because of security reasons.